# How to control Python's stdout encoding under Apache/WSGI

Tags: python, django, apache, encoding, mod-wsgi

I'm writing a Django app, and it prints Unicode to `stdout`. It works perfectly on the development server, but with Apache and modwsgi I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters ...`.

So, the stdout encoding is forced to ASCII. I've found a number of solutions, all of which seem like they should work according to documentation, but none work for me:

- I tried setting the [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) variable to `utf-8`, using the `SetEnv` directive.
- I also tried setting `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` to `en_US.UTF-8` using `SetEnv` and `PassEnv`.
- Since my Apache server is running under `systemd`, I tried setting the variables using `Environment=` directives in the service file.
- Finally, I tried adding `lang=en_US.UTF-8 locale=en_US.UTF-8` to the [`WSGIDaemonProcess`](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html) directive.

The variables are seen in the environment (reflected e.g. on Django error pages in debug mode), but the error still occurs.

Why don't these things work and what should I do? Overriding `stdout` in the code that works fine outside Apache or encoding everything manually doesn't feel like the right approach.

The error occurs at a plain `print` statement. Here's the entire view that raises the error:

```
def test(request):
    import locale
    print locale.getdefaultlocale()
    print locale.getpreferredencoding()

    s = u'привет'
    print s
    return s
```

Apache error log:

```
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
UTF-8
Internal Server Error: /app/testview/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/web/my_site/my_app/views.py", line 964, in test
    print s
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I print `sys.stdout` itself, I see that it's actually a `mod_wsgi.Log` object. In the WSGI file, all I have for logging is:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
```

Versions:
Python 2.7.14,
Apache 2.4.29,
mod_wsgi 4.5.20
on Arch Linux

Comment: What about to `from __future__ import unicode_literals` ? is a workaround to you?

Comment: Though pretty old, we are facing same issue these days. Did you manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

The first two will not do anything as `SetEnv` only sets per request WSGI environ, not process variables.

Adding lang/locale on WSGIDaemonProcess should work in most cases provided you are actually running things in daemon mode. It will not work for embedded mode.

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html

Have you verified you are actually running in daemon mode.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#embedded-or-daemon-mode

Comment: Thank you! I'd seen the post of yours before. Interesting: you write (of env variables): "they need to be set in the environment under which the initial Apache process starts up". Since my Apache server is running under systemd, what I just tried is using `Environment=` directives in a drop-in `override.conf` to set `LANG` and `LC_ALL`. No luck.

Comment: P.S. With the test `application` from the second link I see the (non-empty) `mod_wsgi.process_group` value that I set in the Apache config with `WSGIProcessGroup` directive.

Comment: So setting ``PYTHONIOENCODING`` in systemd config files didn't help either? Could you see that environment variable being set in the WSGI application?

Comment: Yes. `PYTHONIOENCODING` is set but the error is still there.

Comment: What do you get for ``locale.getdefaultlocale()`` and ``locale.getpreferredencoding()`` as described in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html

Comment: Hmm, it's actually `('en_US', 'UTF-8')` and `UTF-8`.

Comment: Even if I don't set any environment variables, I still get that result for `getdefaultlocale()` and `getpreferredencoding()`.

Comment: Can you distil it down to the simplest example code possible and show it? It may be what the code itself is doing that is causing the issue.

Comment: It's a simple `print` statement. I created a separate view and included it in the question.

Comment: Have you overridden ``sys.stdout`` in your WSGI script file or somehow via logging setup? What do you get for ``print(type(sys.stdout))``?

Comment: Interesting! `sys.stdout` is a `mod_wsgi.Log` instance. I also found a `logging.basicConfig` call in the wsgi file, included in the question.

Comment: It is meant to be ``mod_wsgi.Log``. That was what I was expecting.

Comment: The documentation for `lang` and `locale`  is here :  https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that changed `HTTPD_LANG=${HTTPD_LANG-"en_US.utf8"}`

```
$ cat -n /etc/init.d/httpd | grep HTTPD_LANG
    34  HTTPD_LANG=${HTTPD_LANG-"en_US.utf8"}
    59          LANG=$HTTPD_LANG daemon --pidfile=${pidfile} $httpd $OPTIONS
    85      if ! LANG=$HTTPD_LANG $httpd $OPTIONS -t >&/dev/null; then
```